# Count number of files in directory then scp transfer a certain range such as 21404-42806

Tags: scp, ls, wc

I found the number of files in /dev/shm/split/1/ to be 42806 using:

```
/bin/ls -lU /dev/shm/split/1/ | wc -l
```

What I can't seem to find anywhere online is how to select a certain range, say from 21404-42806, and use scp to securely copy those files. Then, for management purposes, I would like to move the files I copied to another folder, say /dev/shm/split/2/.

How do I do that using CentOS?

I tried:

```
sudo chmod 400 ~/emails/name.pem ; ls -1 /dev/shm/split/1/ | sed -n '21443,42806p' | xargs -i scp -i ~/emails/name.pem {} root@ipaddress:/dev/shm/split/2/
```

This produced:

```
no such file or directory
```

errors on all of the files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls` itself lists files relative to the directory you give. This means your `ls` prints the filenames in the directory, but later on, scp doesn't have the path to them. You can fix this two ways:

Give the path to `scp`:

```
ls -1 /dev/shm/split/1/ | sed -n '21443,42806p' | xargs -i \
  scp -i ~/emails/name.pem /dev/shm/split/1/{} root@ipaddress:/dev/shm/split/2/
```

Change to that directory and it will work:

```
cd /dev/shm/split/1/; ls -1 | sed -n '21443,42806p' | xargs -i \
  scp -i ~/emails/name.pem {} root@ipaddress:/dev/shm/split/2/
```

Comment: It is working as we speak. There was an extra \ in your code I removed between xargs and scp commands. Thank you so much!

Comment: The `\` is dividing the command on two lines (basically escaping the newline character) so it is readable in this code block and you can actually copy-paste it to your command-line prompt (Good to know ;-) )

Comment: No problem at all. Thank you once again for your assistance. :)